# Can't manage to cite in IEEE style with document class {book}

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

None of the solutions that I've found on internet have worked with me. I am trying to cite this paper: http://ijarece.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IJARECE-VOL-1-ISSUE-4-52-56.pdf and many other documents as articles and books. I need to use IEEE style.

This is my document style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
....
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %I also tried IEEEtran, and IEEEtranN
\bibliography{literature/library}
\end document
```

This is what I have in my library.bib document:

```
@article{r1,
author = "A. N. Shinde, A. C. Joshi, S.S. Patil, Dr. A.P. Vaidya",
journal = "International Journal of Advanced Research in Electronics and Communication Engineering (IJARECE)",
month = oct,
number = "4",
pages = "1-5",
title = "DC Drive using PWM Techniques For Treadmill",
volume = "1",
year = "2012"
}
```

I'm using \cite{r1} to refer it. 
But when compiling, I get this error:

**! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations**

**SOLVED:**
I went back to use:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```

Now it's working. My problem was I was editing a template which contained some packages that somehow affected my whole code. I just started a new template myself with the stuff I need. I'm starting to learn Latex, and I confess it was a mistake editing an already-made template.

Comment: AFAIK authors in `.bib` files need to be separated by `and` rather than commas, does changing that help?

Comment: I changed it, but still doesn't work. It keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: The message error gives away the solution. The `ieeetr` bibliography style is not compatible with `natbib`. So, removing the `\usepackage[number]{natbib}` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message provides the key clue. The `ieeetr` bibliography style is not compatible with `natbibt`.

The format of a `\bibitmem` required by `natbib` has the following template

```
\bibitem[Author-List (year)]{key} ...
```

While `ieeetr` provides bib items with the following form:

```
\bibitem{key} ...
```

Thus, one option is not to load the `natbib` package (remove `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. The manual for `IEEEtran` suggests to use the `cite` style to manage citation (optionally).

If `natbib` commands are already used in the body of the document, an option could be to use `biblatex`  and the `bib latex-ieee` style, i.e., add the following lines to the preamble

```
\usepackage[style=ieee,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature/library.bib}
```

and then `\printbibliography` where the bibliography should appear it the document. This solution requires to use `biber` instead of `bibtex` to generate the bibliography.